# C++ system function

Tags: c++, batch-file

When I run the command `system("start C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tibia\\Tibia.exe");`

it will show an error at runtime and gives me this output :

> The system cannot find the file C:\Program.

It is the correct path, I checked it thrice! So what is wrong with this command?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the path in quotes as it contains spaces. As normal double quotes would end the C++ string literal, you have to escape them:

```
system("start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tibia\\Tibia.exe\"");
```

A simple `system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tibia\\Tibia.exe")` would likely do the job as well, as this is what the `start` verb does.

Comment: I tried both but it doesn't start the application. When I use start the cmd window stays open and the title changes to the tibia path.

Comment: Nore that, if you run it from a 32 bit application, `C:\\Program Files (x86)` is virtualized to be `C:\\Program Files`.

Comment: i have 64 bit windows 8

Comment: Yes, but whether your application is compiled as 32 bit, or as 64 bit application matters.

Comment: You'll need to do more investigation than throwing up your hands and saying "it doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
system("start C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Tibia\Tibia.exe");
As far as I understand, you need to preceed '\' before a space.